# My JSON api key is not in correct format

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-python-client

I want to make server-to-server requests to Google Analytics. I'm using Python, webapp2, App Engine. Because I use App Engine, I already have service account and I downloaded its API key:

```
{
  "type": "secret",
  "project_id": "secret",
  "private_key_id": "secret",
  "private_key": "secret",
  "client_email": "secret",
  "client_id": "secret",
  "auth_uri": "secret",
  "token_uri": "secret",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "secret",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "secret"
}
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) but `get_access_token()` throws an error. While debugging the library, I discovered the code expects json fields

```
json_data['_service_account_email'],
scopes=json_data['_scopes'],
private_key_id=json_data['_private_key_id'],
client_id=json_data['client_id'],
user_agent=json_data['_user_agent'],
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm using oauth2client that comes with google_api_python_client.

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json()` to load your key file.

This constructor is meant to be used on a serialized `ServiceAccountCredentials` instance, however, and not for a key file as downloaded from the cloud console.

Try using `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name()` instead.

Comment: What would I use if I have contents of key file saved in database instead of file?

Comment: If you store the key in PKCS #12 format, you should be able to use `ServiceAccountCredentials._from_p12_keyfile_contents()`. Note that in this case, you also need to provide the Service Account's email address as an argument.

Comment: But that still requires using file. I want to avoid using file altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but the `_from_p12_keyfile_contents()` constructor requires you to give a string containing a private key in PKCS #12 format, not a file: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/service_account.py#L256