# Python to Google sheets connector without key file

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, oauth, powerbi

I managed to get Python to read from a Google Sheet. However, because I am using the script from within PowerBI to read from a Google Sheet, I can't use the local secret JSON key file on my computer, as PowerBI can't access this file. I currently connect to the sheet as follows:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(r'C:\Users\Laila\Documents\google_spreadsheet_secret_key.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
return gc,credentials
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
secret_key={xxx:xxx}
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(secret_key)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
return gc,credentials
```

Is this possible?

I already tried adding the secret key with JSON dumps and adding it like that, that gives the following error:

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-0b15fbe84ead> in <module>

----> 8 onboarding_yearmonth=get_onboarding_year_month()

<ipython-input-30-ff93a4b40320> in get_onboarding_year_month()
      1 def get_onboarding_year_month():
----> 2     onboarding_sheet = read_onboarding_sheet()
      3     onboarding_row=onboarding_sheet.loc[onboarding_sheet['ID'] == str(client_id)]
      4     onboarding_row = onboarding_row.iloc[0]['Live date']
      5     onboarding_dt = parse(onboarding_row)

<ipython-input-28-d0961c0ce7d1> in read_onboarding_sheet()
      1 def read_onboarding_sheet():
----> 2     gc,credentials = connect_to_gsheets()
      3     spreadsheet_key = '1zeUiWGMWp-xxx'
      4     spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
      5     worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("Onboarding Dates")

<ipython-input-82-7b436cef1e5e> in connect_to_gsheets()
      1 def connect_to_gsheets():
      2     scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
----> 3     credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(secret_key)
      4     gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
      5     return gc,credentials

c:\users\laila\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py in from_json(cls, json_data)
    440         password = None
    441         if pkcs12_val is None:
--> 442             private_key_pkcs8_pem = json_data['_private_key_pkcs8_pem']
    443             signer = crypt.Signer.from_string(private_key_pkcs8_pem)
    444         else:

KeyError: '_private_key_pkcs8_pem'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import re
import gspread
import csv
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
import glob
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendar
import requests
from dateutil.parser import parse
import json
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import _helpers
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import crypt
from oauth2client import transport


def connect_to_gsheets():
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials._from_p12_keyfile_contents(
        "email from service account insert here",
         "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\ xxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        ,private_key_password=None, scopes=scope,
        token_uri="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        revoke_uri=oauth2client.GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI)
   # credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(json.loads(secrets), scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    return gc,credentials
def read_cost_sheet():
    gc,credentials = connect_to_gsheets()
    spreadsheet_key = 'xxxx'
    spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
    worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("DATA")
    list_of_lists = worksheet.get_all_values()
    onboarding_dates=pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)
    onboarding_dates.columns = onboarding_dates.iloc[0]
    return onboarding_dates

cost_data=read_cost_sheet()
print(cost_data)
```

see also here; [My JSON api key is not in correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540629/my-json-api-key-is-not-in-correct-format)

Answer (score 2):

According to [ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json) you can pass already parsed dictionary.

You can copy the file content as string in a variable and then load them as dictionary object using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
import json


# store contents of 'C:\Users\Laila\Documents\google_spreadsheet_secret_key.json' in secrets
secrets = 'STORE_FILE_CONTENT_HERE' # Use single quotation to wrap the content
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(json.loads(secrets), scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
return gc,credentials
```

*Disclaimer*: I have not tested it.

**Reference**

- [ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json)
- [json.loads() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: I tried doing this in several ways, but still getting the error.

Comment: Can you include the error message to the question please?